# unable to connect to TestChain by Code

Tags: solidity, testnets, nethereum, c#, firewalls

I am new at Ethereum and intended to connect to a test chain by c#. my code runs greatly on my old laptop win7, but on newer one Win10 it just waits forever. this is my code. has anyone any idea?

```
   var web3test = new Web3();
   var isMining = await web3test.Eth.Mining.IsMining.SendRequestAsync();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem , it was in my c# code
The function which calls the code was on the wait,

TestConnection().wait(); // this is not proper

so I changed it to TestConnection(); and it works